# Error near "output": syntax error, unexpected output, expecting ')'

Tags: debugging, verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

```
module rc_adder4 (
    input logic[2:0]a, b
    output logic[2:0] s, 
    output logic c_out
    );
    logic [3:0] c;

    rc_adder_slice UUT[2:0] (
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .c_in(c[2:0]),
    .s(s),
    .c_out(c[3:1])

);

// COMPLETE USING ARRAY INSTANCING

    assign c[0] = 1'b0;// COMPLETE
    assign c_out = c[3];// COMPLETE
    
endmodule
```

I tried to run this part, but it said:

> near "output": syntax error, unexpected output, expecting ')'

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

The simulator I use gives a more meaningful error message:

```
    output logic[2:0] s, 
         |
xmvlog: *E,POLICI: Expecting a comma between adjacent port declarations.
```

This is telling you that you need to separate all signals with commas, and you are missing the comma between the last `input` and first `output`.

Change:

```
input logic[2:0]a, b
```

to:

```
input logic[2:0]a, b,
//                  ^
```

---

Sometimes different simulators can give you more helpful messages.  You can sign up for a free account on edaplaygroud to get access to several simulators.